# How to join two lists of data frames obtaining a third list with the joined data frames?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mapply

I have two lists each with 18 data frames that have two columns, one containing ids, the other data. My goal is to fully join the data frames of both lists (the first one of `list1` with the first one of `list2` and so on) by the id column such that the resulting 18 data frames (again stored in a list) each have 3 columns (one id column, two data columns).

Plesae note that the data frames in `list1` do not necessarily have the same length as the ones in `list2`, and that the data column of the data frames in `list1` is differently named than the one in `list2`.

Here is a downsized example:

```
list1 <- list(df1 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:3), data_1 = letters[1:3]),
              df2 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:4), data_1 = letters[1:4]))
list2 <- list(df1 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:4), data_2 = LETTERS[1:4]), 
              df2 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:7), data_2 = LETTERS[1:7]))
```

I guess the solution goes something like this:

```
mapply(function(x, y) {
  # some function with e. g. dplyr::full_join 
  }, x = list1, y = list2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list3 <- lapply(1:length(list1), 
                function(x) merge(list1[[x]], 
                                  list2[[x]], 
                                  by = "id_col"))
list3
# [[1]]
#   id_col data_1 data_2
# 1      1      a      A
# 2      2      b      B
# 3      3      c      C
# 
# [[2]]
#   id_col data_1 data_2
# 1      1      a      A
# 2      2      b      B
# 3      3      c      C
# 4      4      d      D
```

If you want a full join, specify `all = TRUE`

```
list3 <- lapply(1:length(list1), 
                function(x) merge(list1[[x]], 
                                  list2[[x]], 
                                  by = "id_col",
                                  all = TRUE))
list3
# [[1]]
#   id_col data_1 data_2
# 1      1      a      A
# 2      2      b      B
# 3      3      c      C
# 4      4   <NA>      D
# 
# [[2]]
#   id_col data_1 data_2
# 1      1      a      A
# 2      2      b      B
# 3      3      c      C
# 4      4      d      D
# 5      5   <NA>      E
# 6      6   <NA>      F
# 7      7   <NA>      G
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a job for `purrr::map2` :) :

```
map2(list1,list2,~merge(.x,.y))

# $df1
#   id_col data_1 data_2
# 1      1      a      A
# 2      2      b      B
# 3      3      c      C
# 
# $df2
#   id_col data_1 data_2
# 1      1      a      A
# 2      2      b      B
# 3      3      c      C
# 4      4      d      D
```

(adjust the parameters of merge to get the kind of join you desire)

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is with `purrr` to loop through the lists and `dplyr` to do the joining:

```r
list1 <- list(df1 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:3), data_1 = letters[1:3]),
              df2 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:4), data_1 = letters[1:4]))
list2 <- list(df1 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:4), data_2 = LETTERS[1:4]), 
              df2 = data.frame(id_col = c(1:7), data_2 = LETTERS[1:7]))

purrr::map2(list1, list2, dplyr::full_join, by = "id_col")
#> $df1
#>   id_col data_1 data_2
#> 1      1      a      A
#> 2      2      b      B
#> 3      3      c      C
#> 4      4   <NA>      D
#> 
#> $df2
#>   id_col data_1 data_2
#> 1      1      a      A
#> 2      2      b      B
#> 3      3      c      C
#> 4      4      d      D
#> 5      5   <NA>      E
#> 6      6   <NA>      F
#> 7      7   <NA>      G
```

map2 iterates through two lists of equal length, passing the nth element of those lists to the function in the third argument. The fourth argument is also passed to the function.